# computing $A_2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(z_k-1)^2} $ and $\sum_{k=1}^n \cot^2\left( \frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation, roots

Assume that  $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ are  roots of the equation $z^n+z^{n-1}+...+z+1=0$.

> I was asked  to compute the expressions 
>   $$A_1=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(z_k-1)} ~~~~~~and~~~~~~A_2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(z_k-1)^2} $$
>   Then deduces  $$B_2=\sum_{k=1}^n \cot^2\left( \frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)$$

I managed with $A_1$ and proved that $$A_1=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(z_k-1)}=-\frac{n}{2}$$
I  used the fact that $$\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}=z^n+z^{n-1}+...+z+1$$

Actually I couldn't see an apparent link between  $A_1$,  $A_2$ and $B_2$. 
Can anyone help with $A_2$ and $B_2$. [k](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/SamWaltersFourQuestions.shtml?utm_source=spotim&utm_medium=spotim_recirculation&spotim_referrer=recirculation&spot_im_comment_id=sp_QgwMYISL_SamWalters%27FourQuestions_c_RNPVmi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With $A_2$**, it is easy to show that if
$$P(z)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(z-z_k\right)$$
then
$$P'(z)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\prod\limits_{k=1,k\ne i}^{n}\left(z-z_k\right)$$
and
$$\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z-z_i} \Rightarrow -\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z_i-z} \tag{1}$$
and finally
$$A_1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z_i-1}=-\frac{P'(1)}{P(1)}=-\frac{n}{2}$$
However, from $(1)$:
$$\left(-\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}\right)^{'}=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z_i-z}\right)^{'}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(z_i-z)^2}$$
and 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(z_i-z)^2} = -\frac{P''(z)P(z)-P'(z)^2}{P(z)^2} \tag{2}$$
and 
$$A_2=-\frac{P''(1)P(1)-P'(1)^2}{P(1)^2}$$
where 
[$$P''(1)=n(n-1)+(n-1)(n-2)+...+3\cdot2+2\cdot1=\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{3}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292775/proving-12-23-34-cdots-n-n1-fracnn1n23)
thus
$$A_2=-\frac{\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{3}(n+1)-\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{4n-n^2}{12}$$

Answer (score 7):

That is the core of Cauchy's proof of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. The whole proof can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Cauchy's_proof).

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1}\right) = \color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)}{3}}.$$

---

An insane overkill, just for fun. Due to the reflection formula for the trigamma function,
$$ \psi'(s)+\psi'(1-s) = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi s)} $$
we have:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1}\right)=-n+\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\psi'\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)=-n+\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{\left(m+\frac{k}{n+1}\right)^2} $$
where the RHS can be rearranged as
$$ -n+\frac{2(n+1)^2}{\pi^2}\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{M\geq 1 \\ (n+1)\nmid M}}\frac{1}{M^2}=-n+\frac{2(n+1)^2}{\pi^2}\zeta(2)\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)}{3}}. $$

Comment: You mean Euler's proof :)

Comment: @OlivierOloa: no no, I mean Cauchy. Euler gave several proofs, but the proof through such trigonometric identity firstly appeared in the *Cours d'Analyse*, if I recall it correctly.

Comment: Oops, I think you are right... (+1)