# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^m \cot^2 k\pi/(2m+1)=m(2m-1)/3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometric-series

> Prove that $$ \sum_{k=1}^m \cot^2 \frac{k\pi}{2m+1}=\frac{m(2m-1)}{3} $$

I have tried to use $$\sin\left((2m+1)x\right)=
\left(\sin^{2m+1}x\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j \binom{2m+1}{2j+1}\left(\cot^2x\right)^{m-j}\right)$$
and induction without any success. Thanks for any help!

Comment: A few good hints [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615072/computing-a-2-sum-k-1n-frac1z-k-12-and-sum-k-1n-cot2-left/)

Comment: Another hint contained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649011/more-questions-from-mathematical-analysis-by-apostol/) question (the polynomial development part, see the question, not the answer).

Comment: I guess you can find a copy of Cauchy's *Cours d'Analyse* - this is the key ingredient of Cauchy's proof of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. It can be proved in many ways, for instance by applying Vieta's formulas to Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind. You may have a look at [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) too, in the section about the Basel problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to my last comment and given you used
$$\sin\left((2m+1)x\right)=
\left(\sin^{2m+1}x\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j \binom{2m+1}{2j+1}(\cot^2x)^{m-j}\right)=
\left(\sin^{2m+1}x\right) \cdot P\left(\cot^2{x}\right)\tag{1}$$
where 
$$P(x)=\sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j \binom{2m+1}{2j+1}x^{m-j}=\binom{2m+1}{1}x^m-\binom{2m+1}{3}x^{m-1}+...$$
is a polynomial of degree $m$, with (easy to see from $(1)$ since $\sin\left((2m+1)\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right)=0$) $\cot^2{\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}}, k=1..m$ as roots. Using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)
$$\sum_{k=1}^m \cot^2{\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}}=-\frac{-\binom{2m+1}{3}}{\binom{2m+1}{1}}=\frac{(2m+1)(2m)(2m-1)}{(2m+1)\cdot 2 \cdot 3}=\frac{m(2m-1)}{3}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
The $-i\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right)$, for $1 \leq |k| \leq m$, are the distinct roots of $(X+1)^{2m+1}-(X-1)^{2m+1}$.