# What is the value of: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\frac{\cot^2(r\pi/n)}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, summation

> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\frac{\cot^2(r\pi/n)}{n^2}$$

How can I calculate the value of this trigonometric function where limits tends to infinity?  I have thought and tried various of methods like using:

1. Tan(x)/x property
2. Converting lim to
   Integration
3. Sandwich theorem
4. Trigonometric series

But none worked out for me.

So please tell me a good and easy approach for this question :)

Comment: But where exactly are you stuck had you really tried any of these methods? It's way too easy to simply name a few standard methods.

Comment: I m stuck because I cannot use the summation of (1/r^2) which equals to π^2/6 because this is from my exam and therefore I need another approach

Comment: Some useful hints [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615072/computing-a-2-sum-k-1n-frac1z-k-12-and-sum-k-1n-cot2-left/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065615/prove-sum-k-1m-cot2-k-pi-2m1-m2m-1-3/)... and it looks like the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It would be naïve and incorrect to proceed as follows**

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\cot^2(\pi k/n)}{n^2}&\underbrace{\approx}_{\text{WRONG!}} \frac1n\int_{1/n}^{1-1/n}\cot^2(\pi x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1n\left.\left(-x-\frac1\pi \cot(\pi x)\right)\right|_{1/n}^{1-1/n}\\\\
&=\frac2{n^2}-\frac1n +\frac2{n\pi}\cot(\pi/n)\\\\
&\to \frac2{\pi^2}
\end{align}$$

---

Instead, we use $\cot^2(x)=\csc^2(x)-1$ to write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\cot^2(\pi k/n)}{n^2}&=\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^2\,\sin^2(\pi k/n)}\\\\
&=\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1}\frac{1}{n^2\,\sin^2(\pi k/n)}
\end{align}$$

Next, we note that for $\pi/2>x>0$, $\left(x-\frac16 x^3\right)^2\le \sin^2(x)\le x^2$.  Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac2{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1}\frac1{k^2} \le \frac2{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1}\frac{1}{n^2\,\sin^2(\pi k/n)}&\le \frac2{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1}\frac1{k^2\left(1-\frac16\frac{\pi^2k^2}{n^2}\right)^2}\\&=\frac2{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1}\frac1{k^2}+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}$$

whence letting $n\to \infty$ and applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\cot^2(k\pi/n)}{n^2}=\frac13$$

Comment: +1. Nice job.${}$

Comment: @FelixMarin Hi Felix!  Happy New Year.  And thank you.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Happy New Year, Mark Viola.

Comment: @MarkViola Then what is the mistake if I write cot(x) in terms of tan(x), use tan(x)/x property with basel problem where sum(1/k^2)= π^2/6 because that eventually results in with a wrong answer :1/6 though the answer is 1/3.What is my mistake here?

Comment: @ShubhamGawri I'd like to help, but I don't know what you mean by "write $\cot(x)$ in terms of $\tan(x)$" and "use the $\tan(x)/x$ property.  Do you mean $\cot(x)=1/\tan(x)$?  Or do you mean $\cot(x)=\tan(\pi/2-x)$?  Or do you mean something else?  And what is the $\tan(x)/x$ property that you referenced?

Comment: @MarkViola Ok sorry I meant to write cot(x) as 1/tan(x) and multiply divide {π^2/n^2,4π^2/n^2,9π^2/n^2.....so on} so as to evaluate limit using property tan(x)/x =1 when x tends to zero. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: So, you have $$\frac{\cot^2(k\pi/n)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2\tan^2(k\pi /n)}=\frac{1/(k\pi/n)^2}{n^2 \frac{\tan^2(k\pi/n)}{(k\pi/n)^2}}=\frac{1}{\pi^2k^2}\times \frac{1}{\frac{\tan^2(k\pi/n)}{(k\pi/n)^2}}$$Now what?  While $\tan(x)/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$, there are many terms in the series such that $k\pi/n$ is not close to zero.  Keep in mind that $1\le k\le n-1$.

Answer (score 4):

By applying Vieta's formulas to Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind we have
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi r}{n}\right)=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{3} $$
(compare Cauchy's proof of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ in his *Cours d'Analyse*) hence the wanted limit is clearly $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: It's quite short your answer. We were expecting a little more details.

Comment: @FelixMarin: details can be found in [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view). After a few years on MSE, I am growing tired/lazy about re-writing the exact same things over and over.

Comment: Fine. I'll see your notes. Happy New Year 2019. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here I came up with a solution involving only elementary calculation, I hope it's appreciable...

(Sorry as it's in image form)

[image: soln]